# Is there a free SQL formatting library for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net, formatting

I've been looking for a free library/source code to format SQL queries, preferably in .NET, for quite a while. Even after searching some of the responses here on SO, I'm almost at the point where I'm willing to believe that nothing like this exists.

The closest thing I've found, a project called [sqlformat](http://code.google.com/p/sqlformat/), does not seem to be active, nor does it really even support a workable subset of SQLs features for formatting.

Are there any free or open source SQL formatting libraries out there? I don't want a canned product, as I need to integrate this functionality into a tool I'm building. Web services aren't acceptable either, since the ones I have found like [T-SQL Tidy](http://www.tsqltidy.com/) haven't proven to be very reliable.

Comment: Whats the purpose? to reformat the code prior to execution, to fix formatting in a query window, or something else?

Comment: This is an internal tool that allows our developers to reformat text (SQL is just one of the use cases) for revision and consistency. SQL may be spit out of our application in a single-line format, and it's nice to be able to translate it into a readable format as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about a free version, but there is one here for only $100 and you can try it for 60 days (choose the API version).

http://www.dpriver.com/buynow.php

It's not free, but at $100, it's probably less than 2 hours of your time trying to find/integrate a free one

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/sqlformatter has a free kind of api to do it.

Answer (score 15):

I started an open-source .Net 2.0 T-SQL formatting library a couple of months ago, and it's now officially "v1 Done", with no known issues: http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx

I've also set up an online SQL Formatting service (like SQLTidy and several others, except in this case the formatting library that drives it is open-source and fully-functional): http://poorsql.com/

Sorry it's so late, but hopefully this helps someone else out there. Of course, any feedback would be great!

PLEASE NOTE: It's AGPL-licensed, so not appropriate for integration into commercially licensed/distributed applications; but for any sort of internal processes (continuous integration / source control quality) it should be fine.

(Edit: Updated status of the library)

Comment: This library worked really well for me, and there's a Nuget packed for it now too:  http://nuget.org/packages/PoorMansTSQLFormatter/

Comment: Thanks for the licence note. Quote from the website: "If you choose to redistribute/expose the functionality, then you must make the source available to the recipients/users (even of a web service)."  http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx#License__Redistribution_7

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but there were not a lot of good answers.  I had this same question and found this solution for VB6 at VBForums by si_the_geek - one of their super moderators.

[VB Forums Thread for formatting SQL Select (VB6)](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?p=4134712#post4134712)

Having worked with VB6 and VB.NET, it was straightforward to convert.  The bottom of the thread has the VB.NET link or you can get to it straight from here:

[VB.NET SQL Formatting Module](http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=87782&d=1329527927)

You should be able to convert this to C# with one of the online conversion tools without a problem.

Be warned however, the library is not commercial grade code - it works **very** well for fairly simple SELECTS.  For a complex SQL statement with multiple sub-selects, I found errors in the resultant SQL.

Best Regards,

David

ps.   Oh yeah....it's FREE! :)